# Name of the skull painting in Sherlock Holmes The Abominable Bride?

Tags: movie

In the movie there is a painting on the wall in one of the senses:

[image: seen here]

and:

[image: here]

Does anyone know what this is and what it portrays?

I found [this link](https://www.radiotimes.com/news/2018-01-10/7-easter-eggs-you-might-not-have-spotted-in-the-sherlock-special/) and [this link](http://www.denofgeek.com/us/tv/sherlock/251713/sherlock-34-things-you-might-have-missed-in-the-abominable-bride), both mention it as a easter egg type thing but don't mention a name.

Comment: Sorry, but Sherlock Holmes is off-topic for this site as it's not sci-fi or fantasy. I've put your question on hold; if you [edit] in some additional explanation of why this question is interesting and how the painting relates to the story/themes of the film, e.g. by quoting from the links you provide, then I can migrate it and its answer to [movies.se] for you; otherwise, I'm afraid it has to be closed.

Comment: @Randal'Thor With some suspension of disbelief, Sherlock can usually be said to not be scifi, I'll give you that. But _The Abominable Bride_, really, give the OP a break. It takes place in an alternative timeline and features a murderess who is dead at the time of the murder.

Comment: http://clarkesworldmagazine.com/britt_11_10/ | https://www.tor.com/2010/11/18/a-baker-street-irregularity-why-the-bbcs-new-sherlock-is-science-fiction/  - calling Holmes fiction / science fiction is subjective. Also - as the article states, the BBC series takes place in an alternate universe from ours, so that lands it even moreso into topicality

Comment: @NKCampbell - It takes a stretch of the imagination to call wholly mundane crime drama science fiction.

Comment: But why has this not been migrated to Movies and TV?

Comment: @MrLister an alternate timeline explained as a (drugs) trip.

Comment: @SQB Ah, OK, so _Life On Mars_ isn't sci-fi either. Got it.

Comment: @Adamant They'd probably close this as either a trivia question or an ID question. I'm sure I've seen questions similar to this get closed there.

Comment: @Adamant I checked with M&TV mods, and it would need some edits (as indicated in my comment) to be sure of being on-topic there. M&TV has a VTC reason for "trivia", which is admittedly [poorly understood and inconsistently applied](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1809/27759), but this question could easily be closed as such there, without more justification for why the painting is relevant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The drawing is called *All is Vanity* by [Charles Allan Gilbert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Allan_Gilbert). It was originally created in 1892.

[image]